# Quitar emoticonos de los textos python

Tags: python

leí un post de stackoverflow de la comunidad inglesa que daban una función parz quitar todos los emojis , y en parte me funciona quita casi todos los emojis de los textos que extraigo de twitter , pero hay otros que no los elimina , dejo la función aquí por si alguien sabe como podría mejorar esta función , o dar otra posible solución,

```
def deEmojify(text):
    regrex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
    return regrex_pattern.sub(r'',text)
```

ejemplos que fallan :

-RT @JHarden13: Another day, Another opportunity.

-¿qué debo hacer mientras para esperar la 3a temporada?

Comment: Agrega ejemplos mostrando cuando falla. Entrega información que podamos usar para reproducir y probar en nuestros equipos.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta  , se me olvidó adjuntar algún ejemplo donde no se borran

Comment: y que tal si creas la expresion regular para admitir letras y los caracteres especificos que deseas~

Answer (score 0):

El primer ejemplo que pusiste ya se está eliminando, el 2do es:

```
  U+1f92a
```

Podrías agregar sólo ese caracter, o el bloque completo en donde está: Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+1F900)

en los rangos que ya estás eliminando:

```
u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
u"\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF"  # supplemental symbols and pictographs
```

o ser más drástico y eliminar todo el Plano en el que están todos los casos anteriores *Supplementary Multilingual Plane* de U+10000 a U+1FFFF (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/plane/U+1F900)

Unicode tiene una lista de emojis recopilados en https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt (que están dispersos, no necesariamente dentro de un bloque/plano)

Comment: Acabo de hacer de 10000 a 1FFFF , y aún hay emotes que los sigue sin eliminar.

Comment: Este no lo borra por ejemplo: the natural wildlife has returned to the water and forests ❤️

Comment: No conozco una mejor manera. Agregué el link de unicode.org al final de la respuesta, pero como verás esa lista también incluye dígitos 0 a 9... Creo que el problema es que la definición de "emoji" depende mucho del contexto.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la que uso yo siempre, por su facilidad y eficacia.

- Instalo la librería Emoji con `pip install emoji`
- Creo un función que sustituya los emojis por un texto en blanco

```
import emoji

def deEmojify(text):
    return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(r'', text.decode('utf8'))
```

Una vez tienes esta función la aplicas al texto/s que necesites.

La función lo que hace es:

1. Primero obtiene las expresiones regulares de los emojis con `emoji.get_emoji_regexp()`
2. Una vez tienes las expresiones regulares, cade, las sustituyes por un string vacio con el método **sub()** así:  `.sub(r'', text.decode('utf8'))`
3. Con el `return` devuelves el texto original sin emoticonos

Esta librería contiene todos los emojis, y no te tienes que preocupar de las codificaciones, como en el código de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra posibilidad es filtrar los caracteres por su [*Categoría Unicode*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm):

```py
import unicodedata

cat_filter = ["Cn", "Sc", "Sk", "Sm", "So"]  # categorías a filtrar


def deEmojify(text):
    return "".join(c for c in text
                  if unicodedata.category(c) not in cat_filter)
```

Si queremos filtrar algún carácter que pertenece a otra categorías, basta con añadir esa categoría al filtro